# findstr to series output result

Tags: batch-file

I have result like this:

```
13:start_index A3
17:index A3
25:start_index A5
29:index A5
```

But I want it like this:

```
13 17 A3
25 29 A5
```

From begin we have `log.txt` and `note.txt` as shown below:

**log.txt** is:

```
a
A3
b
c
d
e
A5
f
g
h
```

**note.txt** is:

```
start_index A1
a
a
a
index A1

start_index A2
b
b
b
index A2

start_index A3
c
c
c
index A3

start_index A4
d
d
d
index A4

start_index A5
e
e
e
index A5

start_index A6
f
f
f
index A6
```

My Windows batch script is like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM: have two .txt file like: log.txt and note.txt

set errorlogfile=C:\log.txt
set notefile=C:\note.txt

REM: will be used file: index.txt and endindex.txt

if exist %indexfile% del /q %indexfile%
if exist %endindexfile% del /q %endindexfile%
set indexfile=C:\index.txt
set endindexfile=C:\endindex.txt

findstr /n start_index %notefile%>%indexfile%
findstr /n index %notefile%|findstr /v start_index>%endindexfile%

for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%a in (%indexfile%) do (
    findstr %%b %errorlogfile%>null
    if not errorlevel 1 findstr start_index %indexfile%|findstr %%b
    if not errorlevel 1 findstr index %endindexfile%|findstr %%b
)
```

Have anybody a good ideal to get the result like this:

```
13 17 A3
25 29 A5
```

Comment: Don't repeatedly add irrelevant tags like that. [Are the Command Prompt and MS-DOS the same thing?](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). DOS didn't even have `findstr`. It only had `find`. And it doesn't support *delayed expansion*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a commented Windows batch file for this task which can be simply executed from within a Windows command prompt window to get displayed the wanted output for the two files. The two input files are created if not already existing in directory `%TEMP%`. The environment variable `TEMP` can be temporarily for execution of this batch file defined with any directory path.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem set "TEMP=C:\Temp\Test"

set "ErrorLog=%TEMP%\log.txt"
set "NoteFile=%TEMP%\note.txt"

set "CreatedErrorLog="
set "CreatedNoteFile="
if not exist "%ErrorLog%" call :CreateErrorLog
if not exist "%NoteFile%" call :CreateNoteFile

rem Run FINDSTR searching case-sensitive for all lines containing the either
rem string "index" or string "start_index" at beginning of a line and output
rem those lines with line number to handle STDOUT. An error output to handle
rem STDERR is suppressed by redirecting it to device NUL.

rem The command FOR executes FINDSTR in a separate command process in
rem background and captures the output to STDOUT for processing it line
rem by line.

rem Each line is split up into three substrings using colon after line
rem number and space between keyword and the varying string as delimiters.

rem An environment variable is defined with varying string as name enclosed
rem in # to avoid overwriting a predefined Windows environment variable and
rem make sure later for a 100% string match. The value assigned to this
rem environment variable is the start index line number, the index line
rem number and the varying string from note file. Otherwise the line number
rem of the start index line is assigned to a temporary environment variable.

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L /N /C:index /C:start_index "%NoteFile%" 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%B" == "index" ( set "#%%C#=!StartIndex! %%A %%C" ) else set "StartIndex=%%A"
)

rem Read each line from error log file without splitting into substrings.
rem If there is an environment variable with string read from file as name
rem enclosed in #, output the value of this environment variable.

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%ErrorLog%") do if defined #%%I# echo !#%%I#!

if defined CreatedErrorLog del "%ErrorLog%"
if defined CreatedNoteFile del "%NoteFile%"

rem Restore previous environment and exit this batch file.
endlocal
goto :EOF


:CreateErrorLog
(
echo a
echo A3
echo b
echo c
echo d
echo e
echo A5
echo f
echo g
echo h
) >"%ErrorLog%"
set "CreatedErrorLog=1"
goto :EOF

:CreateNoteFile
(
echo start_index A1
echo a
echo a
echo a
echo index A1
echo/
echo start_index A2
echo b
echo b
echo b
echo index A2
echo/
echo start_index A3
echo c
echo c
echo c
echo index A3
echo/
echo start_index A4
echo d
echo d
echo d
echo index A4
echo/
echo start_index A5
echo e
echo e
echo e
echo index A5
echo/
echo start_index A6
echo f
echo f
echo f
echo index A6
) >"%NoteFile%"
set "CreatedNoteFile=1"
goto :EOF
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `findstr` command line with using a separate command process started in background.